# library path when dynamically loaded?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, dlopen

How can I get the path of the shared library from within the library itself?

In other words, let's say that library X is loaded using `dlopen()`, how can I get access to the path that was used to load the said library from within the library itself?

Note that I cannot have the agent that loaded the library in the first place hand me this parameter.

**UPDATED:** Here is way that works with static variables:

```
std::string wdir;

namespace {
    class dynamic_library_load_unload_handler {
         public:
              dynamic_library_load_unload_handler(){
                    Dl_info dl_info;
                    dladdr((void *) NP_Initialize, &dl_info);

                    std::string path(dl_info.dli_fname);
                    wdir = path.substr( 0, path.find_last_of( '/' ) +1 );
              }
              ~dynamic_library_load_unload_handler(){
                    // Code to execute when the library is unloaded
              }
    } dynamic_library_load_unload_handler_hook;
}
```

Comment: Is there an option to set some environment variable with that path?
Is there possibility to write some tmp file (I know...shtty solution :( )

Comment: @bua: if push comes to shove, I'll probably need to "trampoline" on the filesystem... but I am trying to find a cleaner way.

Comment: To my disappointment, on Android dli_fname does not contain the module path, only file name.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The dynamic linker actually searches several places to find each dynamic library. These include (from man ld.so):

- Paths given by the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
- Paths baked into the binary load the library under the `DT_RUNPATH` entry
- The cache file /etc/ld.so.cache
- /lib and /usr/lib

If you want to get the path for a specific shared library, I would recommend the `dladdr` function. From the man page:

> The  function  dladdr()  takes  a function pointer and tries to resolve
>   name and file where it  is  located.   Information  is  stored  in the
>   `Dl_info` structure:
>
> ```
> typedef struct {
>     const char *dli_fname;  /* Pathname of shared object that
>                                contains address */
>     void       *dli_fbase;  /* Address at which shared object
>                                is loaded */
>     const char *dli_sname;  /* Name of nearest symbol with address
>                                lower than addr */
>     void       *dli_saddr;  /* Exact address of symbol named
>                                in dli_sname */
> } Dl_info;
> ```
>
> If no symbol matching addr could be found, then `dli_sname` and
>   `dli_saddr` are set to `NULL`.
>
> `dladdr()` returns 0 on error, and non-zero on success.

So you just give it a function pointer, and it will give you the name of the file which supplies it and a bunch of other information. So for instance, you could have a constructor in a library call this on itself to find out the full path of the library:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((constructor))
void on_load(void) {
    Dl_info dl_info;
    dladdr((void *)on_load, &dl_info);
    fprintf(stderr, "module %s loaded\n", dl_info.dli_fname);
}
```

This function also works on OS X with the same semantics.

Comment: UPDATED: the drawback I found with your solution: other ctors aren't called prior to your `on_load`. Thus, if a C++ variable of some sort is declared static, it cannot be accessed from with `on_load`. Can be annoying.

Comment: @jldupont: The `__attribute__((constructor))` is exactly the same mechanism used for calling constructors of static variables in C++, except gcc makes it available also in C this way. So the order is not specified across translation units. However, gcc does allow you to specify it by adding a priority like `__attribute__((constructor(101)))`. Priority of constructors can be specified by adding `__attribute__((init_priority(500)))` to the class, but I can't find the default priority anywhere. Lower priority means constructor is called earlier and destructor later.

Comment: dl_info.dli_fname not always contain full path in android,see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/cc9b7456b66b7c7c218a9d1f00d7aef1f5ecf409/tests/dlfcn_test.cpp line 141.

Answer (score 1):

since dl_info.dli_fname not always contain full path in android (see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/cc9b7456b66b7c7c218a9d1f00d7aef1f5ecf409/tests/dlfcn_test.cpp#141)),we need to parse the /proc/self/maps to obtain the full path.

```
string GetSelfPath()
{
    string selfPath;
    Dl_info di;
    dladdr((void*)GetSelfPath, &di);
    LOGC("GetSelfPath:%08X,dli_fbase:%08X,dli_saddr:%08X,dli_fname:%s,dli_sname:%s", GetSelfPath, di.dli_fbase, di.dli_saddr, di.dli_fname, di.dli_sname);
    //dl_info.dli_fname not always contain full path in android,see android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/… line 141
    if (strrchr(di.dli_fname, '/') != NULL)
    {
        selfPath=di.dli_fname;
    }
    else selfPath= GetPathByFileName(di.dli_fname);
    LOGC("self path:%s", selfPath.c_str());
    return selfPath;
}

string GetPathByFileName(string targetFilename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");
    if (NULL == fp) {
        return "";
    }
    const size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 256;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = "";
    char path[BUFFER_SIZE] = "";

    while (fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fp)) {
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%*llx-%*llx %*s %*s %*s %*s %s", path) == 1) {
            char *bname = basename(path);
            LOGC("check basename[%s]", bname);
            if (strcasecmp(bname, targetFilename.c_str()) == 0) {
                fclose(fp);
                return path;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I actually needed this on ubuntu too (22.04 on WSL). dl_info.dli_fname was just the file name when I changed LD_LIBRARY_PATH