# C++ How to get a filename (and path) of the executing .so module in Unix

Tags: c++, unix, solaris

C++ How to get a filename (and path) of the executing .so module in Unix?

Something similar to GetModuleFileName on Windows.

Comment: Once you get the path, what do you plan to do with it?

Comment: basically what i want to do is to drop configuration file into the same folder as my .so file, then I need to get a full path to config file and then to pass this full name to xml config parser.

Comment: It's common and recommended to use a [separate path for config files](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/ar01s03.html), so you don't need this.

Comment: @Roger, a separate path should be used, but the "freedesktop" reference is not applicable to all UNIX systems... that would apply to Linux, for example, but not to Mac OS X.

Comment: @Michael: It has sensible defaults for all unix systems, even OS X, which his program can follow if that's what he wants.  In what way do you see things breaking if he does this?

Comment: @Roger, sorry I misunderstood. You are correct. I misintrepeted it as stating that "XDG_CONFIG_HOME" was automatically defined to be "$HOME/.config" by default... not that programs should use "$HOME/.config" by default if it isn't defined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although it is not a POSIX standard interface, the [`dladdr()`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dladdr.3.html) function is available on many systems including [Linux](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), [Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1465/dladdr-3c.html), [Darwin/Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dladdr.3.html), [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dladdr), [HP-UX](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/prot/files/linker/onlinehelp/libraryroutines.htm#dladdr), and [IRIX](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/getdoc.cgi?coll=0650&db=man&fname=/usr/share/catman/p_man/cat3/libdl/dladdr.z).  This function takes an address, which could be a pointer to a static function within the module for example (if cast to `void *`), and fills in a `Dl_info` structure with information including the path name of the shared object containing that address (in the `dli_fname` member).

Comment: If I could still vote, I'd give a +1 for answering original question.

Comment: BTW found answer on SO (was asked 5 months ago): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681060/library-path-when-dynamically-loaded

Comment: Ais far as I can tell, dladdr is _not_ available for AIX. :(

Comment: @graza: You are right; it was available on AIX for Itanium but that was discontinued long ago.  I have removed AIX from my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do that using UNIX or POSIX. If you need to use it to look up some sort of data, you should use the $PATH environment variable and search for the data in a path that is relative to each entry in $PATH. For example, it is not uncommon to store binaries in "*installdir*/bin" for some installation directory "installdir" and to store the associated data in "*installdir*/share/*name_of_program*" for some installation directory and some program named "name_of_program".  If that is the case, then looking at "../share/*name_of_program*/*name_of_resource_file*" relative to each entry in getenv("PATH") is a good way of searching for resources. Another thing you could do is allow the necessary information to be provided on the commandline or in some configuration file, and only perform the search if needed as a fallback option.

**Edit**
Now that you've stated your rationale for this, I would advise you to simply use the [QSettings](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qsettings.html) class from Qt for your configuration information, as it uses the preferred native mechanism for each platform (the registry on Windows, a PLIST file on Mac OS X, the Gnome GConf database on Linux). You may want to take a look at my [C++ Project Template](http://code.google.com/p/cpp-project-template/) as it uses Qt to do just this, and it provides simple commandline options to easily tweak the configuration settings ("--prefset", "--prefget", and "--preflist" manipulate QSettings).

That said, if you absolutely must use an XML configuration file of your own instead of using the preferred native mechanism, I strongly advise you to place the system-wide configuration in "*installdir*/etc" while placing your library in "*installdir*/lib" for some installation directory "installdir", as that is the typical place for configuration files on UNIX systems, and "*installdir*/lib" should ONLY be used for library files, not for configuration files and other errata. I suggest you place a user-specific version of the configuration file in "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME" (if it is defined) or in "$HOME/.config" (where "$HOME" is the user's home folder).

When searching for the system-wide configuration file, I would recommend that you search within $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS if it is defined; if it isn't defined, then falling back to "/etc/xdg" or searching for "../etc/name_of_your_program.conf.xml" relative to "$PATH" and possibly also relative to the "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH", "$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH"), the contents of "/etc/ld.so.conf" if it exists, and the contents of "/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf" if those files exist, halting your search as soon as you encounter the first valid such configuration file would be a sensible approach.

Credit goes to [Roger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54262/roger-pate) for pointing out the [XDG Basedir Spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html#variables) and for his excellent constructive criticisms.

Comment: @Roger, thanks again. You are right again. Maybe you should consider writing a full answer... you'd probably do a better job, and I'd upvote you. In any case, your constructive criticisms are quite helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, but I can't answer as, even though it's what he really wants, it doesn't answer what he actually asked.  (@Steve: You're welcome to change the question to "How do I find configuration for my library/program?" though.. :P)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

- You can read the `/proc/{PID}/mmap` file for the list of shared libraries. Where {PID} is the process pid (you can get it using `getpid()`).
- Call the command line tool `ldd` for the program binary file (stored in `argv[0]`).
- If you write a solution from scratch take a look of `ldd` commands source code from `uClibc` how to get the list of shared libs from an elf binary.