# QPlugin path and initialization

Tags: c++, qt

Does there exist a way for a Qt plugin to determine whether it is being initialized statically or dynamically? If it is being initialized dynamically, is there a way for a plugin to determine the path to its dynamic library (.dll or .so)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [QPluginLoader](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qpluginloader.html) you have two functions you may take a look:

a) `QObjectList QPluginLoader::staticInstances ()`

> Returns a list of static plugin instances (root components) held by the plugin loader.

b) `QString fileName () const`

> This property holds the file name of the plugin.
>   To be loadable, the file's suffix must be a valid suffix for a loadable library in accordance with the platform, e.g. .so on Unix, .dylib on Mac OS X, and .dll on Windows. The suffix can be verified with QLibrary::isLibrary().

Unfortunately, if you don't have plugin loader for specific plugin there is not a lot you can do. Plugins don't require any special interface, and they can be derived directly from `QObject`. Exporting plugin with `Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2` will only declare `QObject` pointer to plugin instance with `qt_plugin_instance` prefix.

Loading the plugin will not call any specific function, so I don't see a way to provide it to the plugin itself.

However, you can do something, if you are willing to lost portability: On Windows, plugins are just dlls, which are accessed [internally by Qt via standard Windows system calls](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/2f4093332db6c9057b82f9c5fababc9bc6cbeb32/src/corelib/plugin/qlibrary_win.cpp) (for example, they are loaded using `LoadLibrary` function, pointers to procedures are found using `GetProcAddress`, and they are released with `FreeLibrary` calls), so you could try [this approach](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16598/Get-Your-DLL-s-Path-Name) (I haven't tested it, it is an ugly hack, but it may work).

```
// near the top of your CPP file
EXTERN_C IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;

// and then, anywhere you need it:
LPTSTR  strDLLPath1 = new TCHAR[_MAX_PATH];
::GetModuleFileName((HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase, strDLLPath1, _MAX_PATH);
```

> It seems that any EXE or DLL compiled with the VS2002 (and higher) linkers provides a psuedo-variable called __ImageBase that represents the DOS header of the module (all 32 bit binaries have this). Simply cast this variable to a HINSTANCE, and you can pass it as the first parameter to GetModuleFileName().

On Unix systems, [plugins are loaded via standard dlopen() system call](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/2f4093332db6c9057b82f9c5fababc9bc6cbeb32/src/corelib/plugin/qlibrary_unix.cpp), so you could use solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681060/library-path-when-dynamically-loaded).

Comment: This is only a partial answer. I agree that `staticInstances()` can be useful, but not `fileName()`, as the dynamic plugin does not load itself and hence does not have access to the `QPluginLoader` instance that loaded it.

Comment: @user1095108 I've edited my post to include a bit more information.

Comment: @user1095108 On Linux/OS X there is even simpler approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681060/library-path-when-dynamically-loaded