# Install Popt locally

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I need to install Popt. Was following [given instructions](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/popt.html), but `make install` requires root permission. My question is:
Is it possible to install Popt locally (without root permission)? And if yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is for your own use within your source code:
you can install it locally and not to `/usr` ***but*** if you run application expects libpopt.so to be located in `/usr` you must to have write permmision to `/usr` in order it to be installed there.

Comment: How can I modify this command `./configure --prefix=/usr` to install Popt locally?

Comment: I guess `./configure --prefix=/path/to/your/locally/dir`, but install it to `/usr` that is why you have `sudo` for

Comment: It was my mistake - I was trying to add `~/` instead of `/home`

Comment: try `./configure --prefix=$(~)`

Comment: I was able to install popt locally using `./configure --prefix=/path/to/your/locally/dir`, but as mentioned I am having problems with my application locating libpopt (`whereis libpopt` gives no results).

Comment: See this answer about how an application finds the path to libs it needs on runtime http://stackoverflow.com/a/1681259/1031417 try to add your directory to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, read the answer more carefully.