# Finding the absolute path of the currently running shared object

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to resolve the following problem:
My code runs on Windows and on Linux. I need to know the path from where the currently running .dll (.so) was loaded, so that I can also find the path to some satellite files I need.
On Windows I use:

```
char buffer[1024];
GetModuleFileName(GetModuleHandle("MyLibrary.dll"), buffer, MAX_PATH);
```

What would be the equivalent code on Linux?

Comment: I have to ask, what is Linus?

Comment: I found something, that may point in the right direction here: [library path when dynamically loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681060/library-path-when-dynamically-loaded)

Comment: How about command `ldd`?